# Cómo registrar hasta 5 usuarios usando PHP y MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysqli, validación

Estoy intentando hacer un registro de usuario para una trivia con validación de DNI , me gastaría que cuando llegue a 5 respuesta ya no pueda mas participar, y no logro. Alguien me puede dar una ayuda?

Ese es mi srcipt

```
$q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM triviacami WHERE dni = '$dni'");

$r=mysqli_num_rows($q);

if($r == 0){
}else{
    mysqli_close($conn);
    header('Location:registrado.php');
}


$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM triviacami");
$fila = mysqli_num_rows($res);
$insertar = "insert into triviacami (id, apellido, nombre, dni, telefono, email, respuesta)
('$id', '$apellido', '$nombre', '$dni', '$telefono', '$email', '$respuesta')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $insertar) or die("Error Al Insertar Datos");
```

ese es el código completo, asi me valida 1 solo dni, pero se cambio de 0 a 5 ya dice ya esta regsitrado.

En realidad dice que el  DNI ya esta registrado a cualquiera que intenta responder la trivia

Muchas Gracias

Comment: hay varios errores en tu código ... de donde sacas la variable `$r`???

Comment: Te recomendaría realizar un count a tu select con groupby a dni, eso lo metas en una sentencia while e igualas $r a lo que te regrese, cuando $r sea = a 5 ahí pones el bloqueo que quieras poner.

Comment: Perdon la variable $r es la conexion

Comment: $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM triviacami WHERE dni = '$dni'");

Comment: Ahi corregi, perdon

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa y ambigua.. que quieren decir varios errores? que erorres?

Comment: Osea que no funciona, si quiere pongo los errores

Comment: Perdón en realidad dice que el el dni ya esta registrado a cualquiera que intenta responder la trivia

Comment: con que codigo dice eso? como es toda la estructura? estas tirando a cuenta gotas el problema.. tomate el trabajo de usar el boton [edit], pone tu codigo para que lo podamos entender y asi darte una respuesta...

Comment: Gracias, ahi pongo en codigo completo

Comment: if($r == 0){ no deberia ser $r <5?????

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra entra al chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 1):

Tu tabla tiene un problema de diseño:

tienes la tabla de registro junto a la tabla de las trivias lo cual no es correcto; lo correcto seria tener una tabla para registro de usuario y otra para las trivias; **¿por que?** se supone que tu tabla de registro debe tener un solo DNI por usuario y no debe repetirse; mientras que ese DNI debe repetirse hasta 5 veces en la tabla de trivia(participación), tenerlo en una sola tabla te genera un conflicto de lógica y alcance de lo que quieres.

Partiendo de lo antes expuesto, Tienes que hacer si o si 2 validaciones una por la cantidad y otra para no repetir el DNI para registro, son 2 querys:

***Función para Validación de DNI registros:***

```
function validarDNIRgistro($conn,$dni){
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM triviacami_usuario WHERE dni = '$dni';");    
    return (mysqli_num_rows($q)==0); //devuelve true en caso de no existir.
}
```

***nota:** aquí se implementa una tabla para usuario.*

***Función para Validación de 5 registros:***

```
function validarNumeroRgistro($conn){
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM triviacami;");    
    return (mysqli_num_rows($q)<5); //devuelve true si hay 5 Usuarios ya registrados.
}
```

***nota:** aquí se implementa una tabla para trivias.*

**Implementación:**

Al final tu código debería lucir así:

```
<?php

    function validarDNIRgistro($conn,$dni){
        $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM triviacami_user WHERE dni = '$dni';");    
        return (mysqli_num_rows($q)==0); //devuelve true de no existir.
    }
    
    function validarNumeroRgistro($conn){
        $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM triviacami WHERE dni = '$dni';");    
        return (mysqli_num_rows($q)<5); //devuelve true si hay menos de 5 trivias del mismo usuario.
    }
    
    if(validarDNIRgistro($conn,$dni)){
        //si no existe debe registrarse el usuario
        mysqli_close($conn);
        header('Location:registrado.php');
    }elseif(validarNumeroRgistro($conn)){
        //si no eciste debe registrarce el usuario
        //si llegas aqui quiere decir que el DNI no se encontró y hay menos de 5 registros
        $insertar = "insert into triviacami (id, apellido, nombre, dni, telefono, email, respuesta) values ('$id', '$apellido', '$nombre', '$dni', '$telefono', '$email', '$respuesta')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $insertar) or die("Error Al Insertar Datos");
    }else{
        //si hay 5 tribias entonces le decimo que llgo al limite.
        mysqli_close($conn);
        echo 'llegaste al limite de intentos.';
    }
```